# how to load a json file with select option click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I'm trying to populate a table with JSON data file but that will happen when I choose an option from select options because each one of them refers to a different JSON data file, what happens is that only the Header of the table that showed beacuse it's already in the html part.

this what I get

[image]

this how it should look like

[image]

this how my code look like

```js
$('#mySelect').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === 'poly') {
     $("#table").show();
        get_json_data('poly.json');
    }
    else{
   $("#table").show();
      get_json_data('mono.json');
    }
});

function get_json_data(json_url) {
    // var json_url = 'example.json';
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log(data);
            append_json(data);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", json_url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function append_json(data) {
    var table = document.getElementById('gable');

    data.forEach(function(object) {
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.innerHTML =
        '<td > <input type="radio" value ="' + object.RendementDuPanneau + '" name="choice" /> </td>' +
        '<td>' + object.Fournisseur + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + object.Modele + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + object.PuissanceMaximale + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + object.RendementDuPanneau + '</td>';
        table.appendChild(tr);
});
  
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

        (elements)[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            const rb = this.querySelector('input[name="choice"]');
            rb.checked = true;

            let selectedValue = rb.value;
            alert(selectedValue);
        });
    }
}
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  color: #384047;
}

form {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #f4f7f8;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

select {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e8eeef;
  color: #202529;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.03) inset;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
legend {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
table {
border: 2px solid #ccc;
border-collapse: collapse;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
table-layout: fixed;
}
.my-custom-scrollbar {
position: relative;
height: 200px;
overflow: auto;
}
.table-wrapper-scroll-y {
display: block;
}

table thead th ,table tbody td
{
  font-size : 12px;
}

tr:hover{
background-color:gray;
cursor:pointer;
}
table tbody td, table thead th {
  text-align: center;

}

table tbody td:last-child, table thead th:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

table tbody td:first-child, table thead th:first-child {
  width: 15px;
  border-right: none;
}
table tbody td:nth-child(2), table thead th:nth-child(2) {
  width: 100px;
  border-left: none;
}
table tbody td:nth-child(3), table thead th:nth-child(3) {
  width: 150px;
}
table tbody td:nth-child(4), table thead th:nth-child(4) {
  width: 80px;
}
table tbody td:nth-child(5), table thead th:nth-child(5) {
  width: 100px;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {

  form {
    max-width: 480px;
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <form action="index.html" method="post" id="formName" name="calculeForm">
       <div id="selecttype" >
                         <legend>Type de panneau : </legend>
                               <select id="mySelect" name="typeP"  >
                                 <optgroup label="Votre Type De Panneau"></optgroup>
                                   <option></option>
                                   <option value="poly">Silicium polycristallin</option>
                                   <option value="mono">Silicium monocristallin</option>
                               </select>
                     </div> <br>
       <div class="table-wrapper-scroll-y my-custom-scrollbar" id="table" style="display:none;">
                       <table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-0" id="gable">
                       <thead>
                       <tr>
                       <th></th>
                       <th>Fournisseur</th>
                       <th>Modèle</th>
                       <th>Puissance maximale</th>
                       <th>Rendement du panneau</th>
                       </tr>
                       </thead>
                       <tbody>
                       </tbody>
                       </table>
                    </div>
    </form>
```

this how my data look like

poly.json

```
[{"Fournisseur":"Jinko Solar","Modele":"JKM270PP-60","PuissanceMaximale":270,"RendementDuPanneau":"16,50"},{"Fournisseur":"Jinko Solar","Modele":"JKM275PP-60","PuissanceMaximale":275,"RendementDuPanneau":"16,80"},{"Fournisseur":"Jinko Solar","Modele":"JKM280PP-60","PuissanceMaximale":280,"RendementDuPanneau":"17,11"},{"Fournisseur":"Jinko Solar","Modele":"JKM285PP-60","PuissanceMaximale":285,"RendementDuPanneau":"17,41"},{"Fournisseur":"Jinko Solar","Modele":"JKM320PP-72","PuissanceMaximale":320,"RendementDuPanneau":"16,49"}]
```

mono.json

```
[{"Fournisseur":"Risen Energy","Modele":"RSM120-6-310P","PuissanceMaximale":310,"RendementDuPanneau":"18,40%"},{"Fournisseur":"Risen Energy","Modele":"RSM120-6-315P","PuissanceMaximale":315,"RendementDuPanneau":"18,70%"},{"Fournisseur":"Risen Energy","Modele":"RSM120-6-320P","PuissanceMaximale":320,"RendementDuPanneau":"19,00%"},{"Fournisseur":"Risen Energy","Modele":"RSM120-6-325P","PuissanceMaximale":325,"RendementDuPanneau":"19,30%"},{"Fournisseur":"Risen Energy","Modele":"RSM120-6-330P","PuissanceMaximale":330,"RendementDuPanneau":"19,60%"}]
```

Comment: If you are using jquery, I really suggest you to use it to retrieve the json file rather than making your own requests manuualy. You can read more about it [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Comment: i think it's the same concept

Comment: `only the Header of the table that showed..` ? can you elaborate this?

Comment: `var tr = document.createElement('tr');`  `table.appendChild(tr);`

Comment: does `console.log(data);` shows right data ?

Comment: You are trying to put `<tr>` inside a `<tr>` when you do `tr.innerHTML =
            '<tr>' +...`. That is invalid nesting

Comment: @Swati i tried `console.log($('#gable').length );` normaly returns full lenght of data but now only return 1

Comment: No i mean to say if you are getting correct values inside `data` because i tested this it should show data inside your table .

Comment: i fixed it bro thanks alot the problem was in the url